# Bottling Advice

Tags: bottling, equipment, wine, mead

I am bottling my first wine soon. However, I am not sure if I should invest in a winged corker, or a floor corker. What are the pros and cons of each, and which should I invest in?

Comment: How many bottles?

Comment: I am doing 1 gallon batches, but I intend to move up to 5 gallons soon. @JamesK

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Floor corker :**

- A bit more expensive
- Much more stable to use
- Bigger, more space required to store

**Winged corker :**

- Less expensive
- Less stable to use (requires much more care)
- Easy to store

I have a floor corker that I bought for about 50$ and I bottled over 100 bottles with it.  The stability is the key, it works so well, no worries to tip a bottle, etc.  I would recommend the floor corker without hesitation.